# how to style nav bar hover state

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to change hover state of nav bar. So for example, I want to make "menu1" highlighted in different color, etc. when I hover over "menu1". Much appreciate help!

```
<div class='header'>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" style= "background-color: <%= mobile_device? ? 'rgba(33, 181, 250,1);' : 'rgba(33, 181, 250,.68);'%> " >
            <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="/" style = "padding-top: 0px; height: 60px;"><%=image_tag("white_text_new_logo.png", height: "60", alt: "Edit Entry")%> <span style="font-size:75%"> </span></a>
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" style="float:right; ">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <% if !current_user %>


                            <li style="padding-left:20px" <%= yield(:active_class) == "borrow" ? "class= \"active\"".html_safe : "" %> >
                                <a href="/borrow">Borrow</a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-left:20px"  <%= yield(:active_class) == "lend" ? "class= \"active\"".html_safe : "" %> >
                                <a href="/listings">Lend</a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="padding-left:20px" <%= yield(:active_class) == "faq" ? "class= \"active\"".html_safe : "" %> >
                                <a href="/faq"> FAQ</a>
```

Comment: "style nav bar menu hover state"...what does this mean? At the very least create a demo in JSfiddle.net and extract that inline CSS to a proper stylesheet.

Comment: Hi, just clarified my question... thank you

Comment: Unfortunately, it's no much clearer...Make a demo perhaps using JSFiddle.net with you actual code (strip out the inline CSS to the stylesheet section) . What `:hover` CSS have you tried?

Comment: What does stripping out the inline CSS exactly mean? sorry really new to this, thanks so much

Comment: It means creating classes and ID so that the styles can be extracted to a separate stylesheet. It looks like you're using bootstrap(?) so you should already have your own custom stylesheet available to you.

Answer (score 0):

If menu1 is a `class`, you can use this css:

```
.menu1:hover {
   /* The CSS, for example:
   background-color: red;
   */
}
```

`:hover` is an example of a pseudo-class. Other examples are `:first-child`, which selects the first element of it's kind inside an element, and `:not(selector)`, which states an exception. The element only has the properties if it's also hovered, or the first child.

You can't use pseudo-classes inside `style` attributes, but you can write this in `<style>` tags an put it in your `<head>`, like this:

```
<style>
   .menu1:hover {
      /* The CSS properties, for example:
      background-color: red;
      */
   }
</style>
```